# How to get record from multiple table using order by

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have a table `"tblStudent"` that has many columns like `"name", "branch_id", "status_id", etc  "tblBranch"` and `"tblStatus"` are child tables of `"tblStudent"`.
I want to get student status detail of every branch i.e

```
**Branches**      **Apply**     **Registered**     **Rejected**
branch1               100             80                20
branch2               150             135               15
branch3               120             115               5
```

Comment: Add sample table data too, producing that result. Also show us your current query attempt. And tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Read up on `JOIN`: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/261/join#t=201610030802306534234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may looking for this :

```
SELECT b.Branches,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status.stausName ='Apply' THEN 1 END) AS Apply,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status.stausName ='Registered' THEN 1 END) AS Registered,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status.stausName ='Rejected' THEN 1 END) AS Rejected
FROM tblStudent s
INNER JOIN tblBranch b ON b.ID=s.branch_id
INNER JOIN tblStatus status on status.ID =s.status_id
GROUP BY Branches
```

Comment: Yes exactl, i could't explain my query, but you got it and solve my problem thankxxx

Comment: How can i get the same result using LINQ query?